# Property for Indefinite Integral

Tags: integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. Assume that there occurs a positive constant $T$ for which
$$
|f(y)| \leq T \int_{a}^{y}|f(t)| d t
$$
for every value $y$ in $[a, b]$. Prove that the equality $f(y)=0$ holds for any $y$ in $[a, b]$.

What could be the major strategies and original intuition behind finding a contradiction if one assumes the existence of some non-zero value? I tried to incorporate the continuity of function and indefinite integral, but it seems no success in mathematical rigor.

Comment: Hint: For the case $a=0$, b=1 use induction to show that $|f(y)| \leq \frac {T^{n}y^{n}} {n!}$ for all $n$.

Comment: You can use Grönwall lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality

Comment: Whoah, this seems a very strong claim indeed. How are you going to prove this inequality? It would be very intriguing for me to see the precise mathematical rigorous proof

Comment: @Tuvasbien Could you exemplify please how the aforementioned inequality will help you to solve the problem? I would be very glad if anyone could provide actual solution for this problem, not any short hints or "unproved" related properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $y \in [a,b]$ define

$$v(y) = e^{-T(y-a)} \int_a^y \vert f(t) \vert \ dt.$$

$v$ is differentiable as $f$ is continuous and

$$v^\prime(y) = e^{-T(y-a)} \left(-T\int_a^y \vert f(t) \vert \ dt + \vert f(y) \vert \right) \le 0$$  according to the given hypothesis. And as $v(a)=0$, you get $v(y) \le 0$ for all $y \in [a,b]$. $v$ being also obviously non-negative is the always vanishing map.

This implies that $f$ is also always vanishing as it is supposed to be continuous (the integral of a nonnegative continuous map $f$ is strictly positive as soon as $f$ takes a nonzero value).

Comment: I think there is a typo above in the integral of new function $v(y)$ $dt$ instead of $dy$, isn't there?

Comment: @BurakKaraosmanoğlu Well spoted. Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome. I also need clarification on some part that confused me. You claim that _"as $v(a)=0$, you get $v(y) \leq 0$ for all $y \in [a,b]$"_ above, but if $0 \leq |f(y)| \leq T \int_{a}^{y}|f(t)| dt$, then $v(y) \geq 0$. How is that possible?

Comment: @BurakKaraosmanoğlu This is exactly what I said in the second part of the answer.

Comment: Aha! After rereading all I grasped the point of my misunderstanding. Thanks!